# Trying to delete a specific character from a string in C?

Tags: c, char, c-strings

I'm trying to delete a specific character (?) from the end of a string and return a pointer to a string, but it's not removing it at all at the moment. What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way to go about it?

```c
char * word_copy = malloc(strlen(word)+1); 

strcpy(word_copy, word); 

int length = strlen(word_copy);

int i = 0; 
int j = 0; 

for (i = 0; word_copy[i] != '\0'; i++) {
    if (word_copy[length - 1] == '?' && i == length - 1){
        break; 
    }
}
       
for (int j = i; word_copy[j] != '\0'; j++) {
    word_copy[j] = word_copy[j+1];  
}
            
word = strdup(word_copy);
```

Comment: `word_copy[length - 1] == '?'` What's the point of that check being done inside a loop? `length` doesn't change so there's no need for a loop. What exactly is that loop trying to do? Is `?` always the last character in the string? Or you are trying to find the first occurence? Or what? Please clarify by providing exact input, expected result and actual result.

Comment: [Does not duplicate](https://godbolt.org/z/e84eE8). Please post real code, see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @kaylum If '?' is the last character in the string, it has to be deleted so I needed to check if it's in that position first before I can delete it. So, Input: Hello? Output: Hello? Expected Output: Hello. However, if it's Input: Hello?? Expected Output: Hello? Output: Hello??

Comment: In that case do you realise you can index straight to the last character - no need for any loop to get to that character.

Comment: I need to check if it's there though right? If I index straight to the last character and it's not what I'm supposed to be deleting, then it's not the output I want.

Comment: What? If you index straight there then you can immediately check if that character is the required value. The for loop does exactly the same thing - it just does it much slower.

Answer (score 0):

I'm immediately seeing a couple of problems.

The first for loop does nothing. It doesn't actually depend on `i` so it could be replaced with a single if statement.

```c
if (word_copy[length - 1] == '?') {
    i = length - 1;
} else {
    i = length + 1;
}
```

The second for loop also acts as an if statement since it starts at the end of the string and can only ever run 0 or 1 times.

You could instead do something like this to remove the `?`. This code will return a new malloced string with the last character removed if its `?`.

```c
char *remove_question_mark(char *word) {
    unsigned int length = strlen(word);

    if (length == 0) {
        return calloc(1, 1);
    }

    if (word[length - 1] == '?') {
        char *word_copy = malloc(length);

        // Copy up to '?' and put null terminator
        memcpy(word_copy, word, length - 1);
        word_copy[length - 1] = 0;

        return word_copy;
    }

    char *word_copy = malloc(length + 1);
    memcpy(word_copy, word, length + 1);
    return word_copy;
}
```

Or if you are feeling lazy, you could also just make the last character the new null terminator instead. Its essentially creates a memory leak of 1 byte, but that may be an acceptable loss. It should also be a fair bit faster since it doesn't need to allocate any new memory or copy the previous string.

```c
unsigned int length = strlen(word);

if (length > 0 && word[length - 1] == '?') {
    word[length] = 0;
}
```

Comment: `The second for loop just removes the first character` No, it removes the *last* character. Note that the second loop executes just one iteration with `j = length - 1`.

Comment: Yea, I just noticed that too. In my first read over I saw `int j = 0;` and thought the second for loop started at 0.

Comment: I thought you have to iterate through a string to delete a character from it - that's why I used the for loop, but the if statement will work just fine?

Comment: @stringy_mozzar3lla you can edit it directly if you know where to look. However if you were going through a Unicode string it might be a different story. With Unicode you have to iterate through since some characters may take multiple bytes. For example, in UTF-16, [this character](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+063F) would be interpreted as a question mark by this code.